# Firebase RealTime DB to Firestore

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I need to switch my data from going to the Firebase Realtime database to the Firestore DB. How do I do that?

The video was primarily focusing on the realtime db but I thought since I did not have a realtime db active it would go to Firestore. But the only way I got it to work was to enable a realtime db. So I am able to insert and read data in Firebase but I need it in Firestore.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no click-through or automated migration path to get from Realtime Database to Cloud Firestore.

You will have to basically do the same data modeling exercise you already did for Realtime Database, and apply it to Firestore. Then you'll have to port your code to the new API manually too.

A good source to learn about data modeling for Cloud Firestore is this video series [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video).

Comment: I figured it out the command to insert and view records are completely different. Thanks.

Comment: I had the incorrect calls. I was using firebase RT calls instead of Firestore calls.